# Tshark - Exporting values of all fields with same name within a list

Tags: wireshark, tshark

With reference to the below S1AP pcap log snapshot

[image]

The highlighted field above is `s1ap.iE_Extensions` which contains a list of items. I need to use Tshark to extract the `id:` field (`s1ap.id`) from `Item0` and `Item1` along with some other fields.

My tshark command looks like below as of now -

`tshark -r test.pcap -Y "s1ap.procedureCode == 9" -T fields -e frame.time  -e s1ap.procedureCode -E header=y -E separator=, > pcap_to_csv.csv`

- need help with exapanding the command so as to get the above fields (`s1ap.id`) for each item in `s1ap.iE_Extensions` list included in the exported file

Comment: I'm not familiar with S1AP but (from your question) i believe that there can be several (more than 2) extensions in a single packet.  The best wireshark/tshark can do is to use a byte range, e.g. `eth.addr[0:3]`; but that could only give you the **first ID** (or a fixed number of IDs if you add the field several times).  I would dump the entire `s1ap` field as the last field in the CSV and do post processing with a scripting language.